# Seeing particular value with form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I like to know why i  can't see the value for name=sjob  when i send this form
i see only the value name=body .
i want to be able to see the hiden input when i reciving the mail
my order: and then the order number that they put in the text box.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<body>
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
        function e_friend(e_add,subject1,body,sjob)
        {
            window.location="mailto:"+e_add+"?subject="+subject1+"&body="+body+"&sjob="+sjob;
        }
    </SCRIPT>
    <form name="e_form" enctype="text/plain">
    The purpose of the reference<br />
        <input name="subj" id="natan" type="radio" value="Need Quotation" />Quotation - Quotation Needed<br />
        <input name="subj" id="lior" type="radio" value="Job Status" />Job Status and Marketing <br />
        <input name="subj" id="acc" type="radio" value="Accounting Info" />Accounting - Information<br />
        <input name="subj" id="mazkira" type="radio" value="Information" />Office  - General Information 
        <br /><br / >
        For Job Status please enter your order Number <br /> <input name="body" type="hidden" value="My Order :" />
        <input name="sjob" type="text"  /><br /><br />
        Select your mail Recipient<br />
        <input name="emadd" type="radio" value="natan@lev-dies.com" />Natan - CEO  <br/>
        <input name="emadd" type="radio" value="lior@lev-dies.com" />Lior - Marketing  <br/>
        <input name="emadd" type="radio" value="acc@lev-dies.com" />Roni - Accounting  <br/>
        <input name="emadd" type="radio" value="mazkira@lev-dies.com" />Office <br/><br /><br />
        <input type="button" Value="I've selected the recipient, Let's send mail!" onClick="e_friend(this.form.emadd.value,this.form.subj.value,this.form.body.value,this.form.sjob.value)" />
    </form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This html code is not valid. You have to close your tag `<head>`before openning the body

Comment: In the original code it exist incidentally I did not put it here

Comment: When testing your code, I'm  not seeing anything at all in the body of the mail, other than "My order :". And the To: and Subject: fields read: undefined.